# How to properly set ALSA mic input on jesse linux image

Tags: audio, alsa

I've spent a few days troubleshooting with other online sources how to set the USB mic as the primary recording card for ALSA.

The error I'm getting is when trying to record content.

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

When I run `cat /proc/asound/modules` I receive this output:

```
0 snd_bcm2835
1 snd_usb_audio
```

Files that have settings are `/.asoundrc`

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

Also my `alsa` command is not running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to record the audio?  `arecord -vv <some file>`?  (does `-vv` give more errors?)

Comment: @grochmal only error that shows is this one ```arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory```

Comment: If you enter `alsamixer` and select your sound card (`<f6>`) and then select all devices (`<f5>`) how does it look?  If you could add a screenshot would be useful.

Comment: Soundcard 0 - ALSA bcm Soundcard 1 - USB [image](https://s31.postimg.org/gyo739q0b/Screen_Shot_2016_07_23_at_6_35_59_PM.png)

Comment: When you select the card and then do `<f5>` a long (wide) list of devices with sound scrolls should appear.  How does it look?  (also, it is good to update the question itself with the image)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion just updated the image - got alsamixer to show USB defaults. Now just having issue with mic detection default w/ my node script